# pytz difference of 2 datetimes in seconds? (Different time zones)

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I have 2 datetime objects with 2 different time zones:

datetime1 = 18:26:23, with tzinfo = UTC

datetime2 = 14:30:00, with tzinfo = US/Eastern

Both dates are on the same day.

There should be exactly 1 hour, 3 minutes and 37 seconds difference between the 2 datetimes, which is: 3817 seconds total difference.

However, when I use the following code to compare:

```
time_diff = (datetime2 - datetime1).total_seconds()
```

time_diff gives me a value of: 3576.

Am I doing the difference in seconds wrong? Or am I not utilizing pytz for time zones correctly?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you put this in the form of a short but complete program?

Comment: What are the dates on these datetimes, and how have you imbued the timezone? Starting with `US/Eastern` without a date gives you the _original_ version of that timezone (which was 19:04:00 GMT, not an even hour), not the _current_ version. If you then pack a date into the already-aware-of-the-wrong-offset time, you keep the wrong offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two likely scenarios here.

1. Either you are creating the timezone on your datetime objects incorrectly
2. The timezone is correct but your datetime objects are not actually representing the time you say they are.

For example, regardless of timezone, I don't see how the diff between `18:26:23` and `14:30:00` could possibly give you an even number of seconds, which makes scenario #2 more likely.

Can you print the value of the `datetime` objects right before you run the line:

```
time_diff = (datetime2 - datetime1).total_seconds()
```

Here is some sample code for reference that gives you the expected seconds:

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
utc = timezone('UTC')
datetime1 = utc.localize(datetime(2002, 10, 27, 18, 26, 23))
datetime2 = eastern.localize(datetime(2002, 10, 27, 14, 30, 00))
time_diff = (datetime2 - datetime1).total_seconds()
print(time_diff)  # prints 3817
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his problem, because his problem is almost certainly that he created the datetime objects wrong, and just showing that completely different code works isn't much help.

Comment: And I can just as easily provide an example that _doesn't_ work. Try the same thing with a DST time line 2002-07-27, or a time before EST changed like 1890-10-27.

Comment: good points, I suspect the timezones aren't the issue and his `datetime` objects don't represent the time he thinks it does.

Comment: Try it with 1890 and the results exactly duplicate what he's seeing. That's why I think the timezones _are_ the problem—or, rather, the way he's trying to create aware datetime objects from those timezones is the problem. But without seeing his code, there's no way to tell him what he's doing wrong, except a vague guess.

Comment: You guys are absolutely correct. I created the datetime wrong. My original code created the datetime by passing in a timezone object into the creator, instead of using the localize function.

Answer (score -1):

doc for timedelta:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

```
def make_timedelta(seconds):
        return timedelta(days=seconds // 86399, seconds=seconds % 86399)
```