# Python 3 time: difference in seconds between two timestamps

Tags: python, time, timestamp

I have two timestamp strings. I want to find the difference between them in seconds.

I've tried:

```
from time import gmtime, strptime
a = "Mon 11 Dec 2017 13:54:36 -0700"
b = "Mon 11 Dec 2017 13:54:36 -0000"

time1 = strptime(a, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
time2 = strptime(b, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")

time1-time2
```

Getting an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'time.struct_time' and 'time.struct_time'

So, how do I calculate the difference using package time?

I was successful using package datetime - in the code below, but I think I read that datetime ignores seconds in leap years, or something to that effect. Thus, I am trying to use 'time':

```
from datetime import datetime
time1 = datetime.strptime(a, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
time2 = datetime.strptime(b, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
dif = time1 - time2
print(int(dif.total_seconds()))
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: "but I think I read that datetime ignores seconds in leap years" Where did you read that? I think it might ignore leap *seconds* which are added occasionally with no real pattern, but that *probably* isn't going to matter.

Comment: Sorry, you are right - it ignores leap seconds

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928815/calculate-date-time-difference-python I think this should give you some insight

Comment: @user3245256: if you care about leap seconds, the `time` module is not going to do any better. `time` and `datetime` use the same underlying system time information.

Comment: Also see https://bugs.python.org/issue23574, mostly leap seconds are ignored for simplicity, especially because using deltas to calculate future timestamps is guaranteed to contain off-by-as-yet-unannounced-leap-seconds if you didn't. Leap seconds are added with only 6 months notice, you can't account for them in any meaningful way when dealing with datetimes modeling a future further away than that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, it makes sense. In this case, it doesn't really matter and my question is not super-useful. My datetime solution works, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're using [time.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime), which returns `<class 'time.struct_time'>`, and it doesn't support the substract operator, one possible way to achieve what you want would be converting to datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime
from time import gmtime, strptime

a = "Mon 11 Dec 2017 13:54:36 -0700"
b = "Mon 11 Dec 2017 13:54:36 -0000"

time1 = strptime(a, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
time2 = strptime(b, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")

print(datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(time1))-datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(time2)))
```

Or even better, use [datetime.datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) so you don't need intermediate conversions.

For a more detailed description of the supported operations of datetime please refer to the section `supported operations` in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime). Especially the section where it says:

> If both are aware and have different tzinfo attributes, a-b acts as if
>   a and b were first converted to naive UTC datetimes first. The result
>   is (a.replace(tzinfo=None) - a.utcoffset()) - (b.replace(tzinfo=None)
>   - b.utcoffset()) except that the implementation never overflows.

In any case, maybe your best chance is considering an alternative method like the one proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30380944/3809375)

Comment: @user3245256 Yeah, the above code is showing you how to use the `-` operator of datetime, as you can see it'll ignore the last part of your strings `a` and `b`. Try to change b to something like `b = "Mon 11 Dec 2017 13:54:31 -0000"` so you'll observe the difference.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand. My b is what it is. The result should be 7 hours in difference expressed as seconds.