# Datetimes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have two dates

```
'2017-03-10 19:01:27'
'2017-03-11 07:35:55'
```

I would like to get the difference one day. How can I do this with the time zone in mind?

Because the time zone of these dates is not known to us. I'm new in Python

I have:

```
from_zone = tz.tzutc()
to_zone = tz.tzlocal()

date_first = datetime.strptime(args[0], time_format)
date_second = datetime.strptime(args[1], time_format)

rep_date_first = date_first.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
rep_date_second = date_second.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)

timezone_date_first = rep_date_first.astimezone(to_zone)
timezone_date_second = rep_date_second.astimezone(to_zone)

day = timezone_date_first.day - timezone_date_second.day
```

day return me 0, How to fix it? Please help me

Comment: What is your local time zone? You are converting these naive timestamps to UTC, and then to your local time zone. Perhaps these datetimes have the same day when expressed in your local time zone.

Comment: This answer will help you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380678/pytz-difference-of-2-datetimes-in-seconds-different-time-zones

Comment: My local time zone Europe/Warsaw

Answer (score 0):

By changing the timezone you're probably adding or subtracting enough hours to your dates that they end up on the same day. You should probably just assume a timezone as you're converting them from strings – or just leave them naive datetime objects.

```
>>> d1 = '2017-03-10 19:01:27'
>>> d2 = '2017-03-11 07:35:55'
>>> date_first = datetime.strptime(d1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> date_second = datetime.strptime(d2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> date_first.day
10
>>> date_second.day - date_first.day
1
```

Answer (score 0):

`arrow` module is a big friend to everyone working with dates, you achive a shift very easily.

```
import arrow
dt = arrow.get('2017-03-10 19:01:27')
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo='Europe/Warsaw')
dt2 = dt.shift(days=-1)
assert dt2.isoformat() == '2017-03-09T19:01:27+01:00'
```

What you are asking a bit amigous: `I would like to get the difference one day` and your code is not runnable in isolation (`args[0]`), but I think you can assume the dates are in the same timezone.